# Using nginx try_files and custom error pages for the main location block?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

When using try_files in nginx, is there a way to specify and use a custom error_page only after it has tried each URI specified in the try_files directive?

The below configuration does not work:

```
location / {   
    if (-f $document_root/error_page.html ) {
        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 495 496 497 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 /error_page.html;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect_store;
}
```

It would seem that if you use an error_page directive, when nginx can't find the passed in URI, it immediately returns the custom 404 error page instead of trying the next entry in try_files.  It seems that the error_page directive overrides try_files?

I can only get this to work when no error_page directive is specified:

```
location / {   
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect_store;
}
```

But in the above case, if each entry is tried and it's still not found, it returns the default 404 error page, but I want it to return a custom one.

Anyone know how to achieve this, or is it not possible?  Is this a bug in nginx?  I should be able to use a custom error_page with try_files assuming a URI was not found in any of the try_files entries.

To summarize, try_files does not go through the chain of entries if the error_page directive is specified.

Comment: Have you tried it with a naked `error_page` directive, rather than inside an `if` block?

Comment: I just tried removing it from the if block, and it appears to work.  However, in my case, I guess it doesn't make sense to use it as a 404 error because my redirect command will always exist in the try_files structure.  Why would the if block affect it like that?  I don't understand why removing that worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with what you are trying to do:

- the `if` block is not behaving as you would like
- any 404 response is unlikely to originate from within your `location /` block

[This document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) explains why the `if` block should only be used in very specific situations.

The final action of your `location /` block is to call the named location `@redirect_store`. If any 404 response is generated, it is likely to occur after processing has left the `location /` block. Therefore any `error_page` directive declared only within the `location /` block's scope will be ignored (irrespective of the `if` block issues noted above).

The final line of the `error_page` document states that:

> If uri processing leads to an error, the status code of the last
>   occurred error is returned to the client.

Which means that your protective `if` statement is unnecessary anyway.

Try this instead:

```
error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 495 496 497 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 /error_page.html;

location / {   
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect_store;
}
```